# Phonegap Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA returing old captured image in iOS

Tags: image, cordova, camera, capture

While using Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA API in iOS its returning last or very first captured image on next successful capture call, but its working fine in Android and returning the actual captured one.

Another thing, Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY is working fine and returning actual picked image each time for both iOS and Android.

Is there any thing wrong with the Phonegap camera APIs used for iOS?

Is there any sample app available to test the Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, which is working fine?

Comment: Probably not an 'Answer', but we found that calling the `cleanup()` function of the plugin seemed to reset the numbering of files created in the tmp folder that it uses, but did not actually remove the old files.  So you would take cdv_image_001.jpg (for example), then cdv_image_002.jpg, then call `cleanup()`, take a new photo, the plugin thinks you just took cdv_image_001.jpg but the old cdv_image_001.jpg file is still there, so you get given the first image you took rather than the most recent.  We think this behaviour is the same on android and iOS.  We no longer call `cleanup()` ever :)